# Loading data from external website with jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

So, I've tried loading some data from an html class at an external website. The external website is not my domain nor do I have any control over it's content or accessibility.

The external website is a website with open data, owned by the gouvernment and serves as a freight business registery with information about freight/trucking companies.

It does not yet have an api for the information I am seeking so I have had to try some different routes to get this working, but I have yet to find a solution that really works.

When I perform a search on the external website and get the content I am looking for it throws several 404 errors, while still retrieving the desired results. So to make it clear, I do get the search results, but I also get 13 404 errors.

This is my jQuery:

```
    jQuery( "#transporterSearchResult" ).load( "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.vegvesen.no/kjoretoy/yrkestransport/tillatelser/Oppslag+i+transport%C3%B8rregister?organisasjon=976874854&hits=10&S%C3%B8k=S%C3%B8k .table", function() {
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
```

How do I get this working the right way, and what is really the best way to achieve what I am after, i.e loading content from a div at an external website?

Comment: If you check the actual URLs being shown in the 404 errors (which you can do in this fiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/7jbr5oyp/) they are coming from the relative URLs defined in the HTML you load; mostly `img` elements. To fix this you will need to manually update the HTML you append to have absolute URLs.

Comment: I see @RoryMcCrossan, but I'm a little confused when it comes to your solution. How would I go about updating the HTML to have absolute URLs?

Comment: Make an AJAX call to the URL (using `ajax()`, not `load()`) then find all `img` elements and update their `href` attributes. You'll need to do the same if there's other elements with relative paths. Better still, amend the content you're loading to be in the format you want instead of having to hack it around.